# Как оптимизировать добавление в коллекцию?

Tags: c#

У меня есть есть объект Trie, содержащий коллекцию с историей изменений.
Выглядит это вот так:

```
public class Trie {

   public ObservableCollection<ReceivedHistoryMessage> History { get; set; }
            = new();

   public void AddToHistory( MqttMessage mqttMessage )
   {
        if ( History.Count >= 100 )
        {
             Count = 0;
             History.Clear();
        }

        History.Insert( 0, new ReceivedHistoryMessage
        {
             Time = DateTime.Now,
             Message = mqttMessage
        } );
        Count++;
   }
}

public class ReceivedHistoryMessage
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public MqttMessage? Message { get; set; }
}
```

Объектов Trie много, кол-во объектов History много, поэтому все как-то подтормаживает. Стоит еще отметить, что всегда я просматриваю в дереве историю только одной ноды, не все коллекции нужны всегда
Как все это можно оптимизировать?

upd:

попробовал убрать Insert, но т.к мне нужно вставка в начало, сделал следующее:

```
public class Trie
{
    History
       .Connect()
       .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler) // to run on background thread
       .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<ReceivedHistoryMessage>.Descending(e => e.Id))
       .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler) // this needed because UI updates need to run on the main
       .Bind(out _uiHistoryMessages)
       .DisposeMany()
       .Subscribe();
}
```

а использую такие коллекции:

```
public SourceList<ReceivedHistoryMessage> History { get; } = new();
private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReceivedHistoryMessage> _uiHistoryMessages;
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReceivedHistoryMessage> UiHistoryMessages => _uiHistoryMessages;
```

`History` используется для добавления в методе `AddToHistory()`

**ничего существенно не поменялось**

Comment: Коллекции не предназначены для большого количества элементов. Храните в БД, используйте пагинацию

Comment: `Count = 0;` зачем очищать? Быть может просто удалять старый, добавлять новый? Зачем `Count`, если есть `History.Count`?

Comment: я просто это свойство потом в другом месте использую, но может вы правы, это избыточно @aepot

Comment: бд не нужна в данном случае, как я думаю

Comment: я вот попробовал сделать Lazy<ObservableCollection>.., но как-то не вижу отличий

Comment: `Insert( 0` - вставка в начало приводит к тому, что все остальные элементы сдвигаются. Хоть элементов не больше ста, но всё же это накладно. Лучше добавлять в конец коллекции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov скорее всего именно в этом и проблема

Comment: так а что именно тормозит? Добавение само? Если отписать коллекцию от всех событий, то тоже будет тормозить?

Comment: `мне нужно вставка в начало` можно поинтересоваться для чего?

Comment: @iiKuzmychov Мне кажется за это вполне понятно отвечает название класса `ReceivedHistoryMessage`. У человека некая история сообщений, получаемых по протоколу MQTT, ну а на экране сообщения некоторые отображают, наоборот, чтоб новое было всегда сверху. Вот только зачем выводить все сообщения истории на экран разом, это вот вопрос хороший. Обычно в таких ситуациях, как сказали прям первым комментариям, делают пагинацию (разбивают на страницы), либо подгружают новые данные при скроле небольшими пачками из базы или еще от куда.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть дерево, у каждого узла есть история, которая сохраняется в коллекцию. Я добивался того, чтобы в истории было около 5-10 элементов, поэтому пагинация не нужна. Еще раз: представьте, что у вас есть дерево, вы нажимаете на элемент дерева и наблюдаете историю изменений именно этого элемента, у других своя история. Сейчас вроде +- оптимизировал, все хорошо стало.

Comment: меня лишь пугает нагрузка в размере 10 процентов для декстопного приложения. Мне кажется, многовато :)

Comment: @penancewarrior Понимаете в чем дело... Вот у вас грубо говоря механика приложения "чат". Где у всяких мессенджеров хранятся все сообщения? Правильно, база, ибо база именно и создана для того, чтобы максимально быстро получить/положить данные, не храня при этом все в памяти (зависит от базы), к тому же это отказоустойчивость. Я вам советую использовать хотяб простой SQLite без установки сервера, это будет на много лучше, чем хранить просто объекты в некой коллекции, особенно, если их у вас много (как вы и говорите). Нажали на узел, отправили запрос в базу, выгрузили 10 объектов, отобразили.